# Bind actions to mouse motion in linux (X)?

Tags: linux, mouse, user-interface, xorg, bind

Is anyone aware of way of binding actions to some key combination + mouse motion? Primary idea would be lets say if alt is pressed and mouse is moved - it would act like scroll wheel (sending scroll wheel clicks can be done easily if I could just run commands on alt + [mouse moves right] for example). So is there a way to do this? Not application specific and not window manager specific. Something like xbindkeys.

Answer (score 0):

There might already be software for that specific purpose. Check out this article

[Easystroke Makes Mouse Gestures Easy in Linux](http://lifehacker.com/5049268/easystroke-makes-mouse-gestures-easy-in-linux)